# Json.decode doesn't work with json from assets

Tags: json, flutter, decode

This line doesn't work, and the code gets stocked there.

```dart
 var list = json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>;
```

The response String that I submit is:

```dart
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/madrid.json');
```

With this JSON:

```json
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -3.7026,
        "lat": 40.4165
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 297.84,
        "feels_like": 297.62,
        "temp_min": 294.82,
        "temp_max": 299.94,
        "pressure": 1017,
        "humidity": 48
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.34,
        "deg": 270,
        "gust": 2.68
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1631051279,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 2007545,
        "country": "ES",
        "sunrise": 1630993686,
        "sunset": 1631039875
    },
    "timezone": 7200,
    "id": 3117735,
    "name": "Madrid",
    "cod": 200
}
```

The line doesn't execute and gets stuck there. I tried with other JSON responses, and it worked, but I don't know why this one doesn't.

Comment: what do you mean by get stuck and does not work? is there an error or something?

Comment: i tried to json.decode your json data at https://dartpad.dev/ and it works just fine

Comment: I have this error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Comment: ok i just tried: `print(json.decode(str));` - your data is a `Map`, not a `List`, so you need `as Map<String, dynamic>;`

Comment: I get the following error when I change from a list to a map: Expected a value of type 'Coord', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Answer (score 0):

remove ***as* *List<dynamic>*** from

The problem is you are trying to decode Map data as List

---

If you face **Unable to load asset**  error add your json path into pubspec.yaml

---

You need to make sure json is response the same type  if want to typecast.

Following json will work fine with ***as* *List<dynamic>***

```
[
  { "key1": "value" },
  { "key2": "value" },
  { "key3": "value" },
  { "key4": "value" }
]
```

Example with above json file

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/list.json');
var dataTypeCast = json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>;  
print(dataTypeCast.runtimeType); //List<dynamic>
```

better approach is removing type casting when decoding unknown response

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/list.json');
var data = json.decode(response);
print(data.runtimeType); // List<dynamic>
```